# Connect to Azure SQL replica from Azure App Service

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have an Azure App Service that connects to an Azure SQL Database.
The Database has a READABLE geo-replica in a different region (different SQL server and different SQL Database name).

I need to connect to the read-only replica from code and I thought it will be enough to:

- get the connection string from the main database
- add to it ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly

But then when I check the queries that run on the SQL database, I see nothing on the replica and on the primary database I see queries that should have targeted the read-only replica.
This is the query I use:

```
SELECT
    deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], 
    dest.TEXT AS [Query]
 FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY 
    deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

I expect to see the queries on the replica, but instead they appear on the main database. So not sure what am I doing wrong.

I have tried to create an SQL user on the replica and use that one, but I got this message:

```
Msg 3906, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
Failed to update database "test-replica" because the database is read-only.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a premium/business critical local readable replica can be redirected with ApplicationIntent.  With [Active geo-replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview) you choose between the two server names, and [Auto-failiover groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-sql-db?tabs=azure-powershell) adds "a stable connection endpoint and automatic geo-failover support in addition to geo-replication".

Comment: The database is on Business Critical tier but it does not work. For me it is a it strange to use the connection string from the master database and just add ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly and to assume that all the database calls will be redirected to a different server and different database.

Comment: I think this is the problem: 
Query Performance Insight relies on data from the Query Store, which currently does not track activity on the read-only replica. Query Performance Insight will not show queries which execute on the read-only replica.

I have checked in code SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Updateability') -> returns READ_ONLY, but I do not see the queries on the replica and I assume the reason is that they are not available